# SegNet - train my own dataset

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

Im trying to train my own dataset on SegNet (with caffe), I prepared the dataset same as [segnet tutorial](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/projects/segnet/tutorial.html). when I try to run the train, it shows me this error:

```
I0914 11:38:04.496928 37274 layer_factory.hpp:74] Creating layer data
I0914 11:38:04.496963 37274 net.cpp:90] Creating Layer data
I0914 11:38:04.496974 37274 net.cpp:368] data -> data
I0914 11:38:04.497005 37274 net.cpp:368] data -> label
I0914 11:38:04.497020 37274 net.cpp:120] Setting up data
I0914 11:38:04.497033 37274 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:41] Opening file /home/ubuntu/full_conv_net/train.txt
I0914 11:38:04.497061 37274 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:51] Shuffling data
I0914 11:38:04.497422 37274 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:56] A total of 0 examples.
*** Aborted at 1473853084 (unix time) try "date -d @1473853084" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @     0x7fd912325f20 (unknown)
*** SIGSEGV (@0x0) received by PID 37274 (TID 0x7fd9132a8a40) from PID 0; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fd911cc6cb0 (unknown)
    @     0x7fd912325f20 (unknown)
    @     0x7fd912b84a5c std::operator+<>()
    @     0x7fd912bc0fa0 caffe::DenseImageDataLayer<>::DataLayerSetUp()
    @     0x7fd912ba2e09 caffe::BasePrefetchingDataLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
    @     0x7fd912b16be3 caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @     0x7fd912b18952 caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @     0x7fd912afebf0 caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @     0x7fd912affbc3 caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7fd912affd96 caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @           0x40c5d0 caffe::GetSolver<>()
    @           0x406611 train()
    @           0x404bb1 main
    @     0x7fd911cb1f45 (unknown)
    @           0x40515d (unknown)
    @                0x0 (unknown)
```

I tried to do `make clean / all / test / runtest` but it still dosnt work. 
thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following error

```
I0914 11:38:04.497033 37274 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:41] Opening file /home/ubuntu/full_conv_net/train.txt
I0914 11:38:04.497061 37274 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:51] Shuffling data
I0914 11:38:04.497422 37274 dense_image_data_layer.cpp:56] A total of 0 examples.
```

This indicates that the network was unable to find the training data. Check that the 'train.txt' is in the correct format. It is better to include the entire the path of the image in the .txt file.